# How check from which expression file was created PDF file?

Tags: c#, file, pdf, jpeg, tiff

It's possible to check from which file PDF was created?

I want to know whether PDF is created from JPEG or TIFF.

If it's possible to check in c# how can I do it?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: and what have you _tried yourself_ so far to achieve this?

Comment: I have used program "ExiftoolGUI"

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to determine for a given pdf creator program which format bitmap images it has embedded in its result pdfs originally had.

But there also may be pdf creator programs that convert bitmap images to embed into a single format first.

Thus, as general as you ask,

> It's possible to check from which file PDF was created?

the answer is **no**.